# Ruby on Rails: testing if values do exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I'm trying to test if my values are existing... Not sure how to do this, I'm just starting to learn Ruby on Rails. Hopefully someone can point me to the right direction?

Lets say I have this block of codes:

```
@lv = {'apple' => ['red', 'round'], 'iPhone' => ['device', 'phone']}

if params[:var]
    @lv.each do |key, tags|
        if params[:var] == key
            lvtags = @lv[params[key]]
            lvtags.each do |tag|
                @tags = client.tag_recent_media(tag)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I'm trying to see if the loop through the `if params[:var] == key` works. I'd like to somehow output like an `alert()` type thing, to test if `key` has a value? Is there something like `alert(key)`? where it'll show if `key` has something? Or if I can test if `lvtags` has a value that its supposed to pop out?

For instance, if `?var=0`

Then I'd like to test `alert(lvtags)`, and thus this is supposed to pop out `apple` or something, some value associated to `lvtags = @lv[params[key]]`. How do we normally test something like this in rails?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `puts key`. [Puts](http://apidock.com/ruby/IO/puts) converts its first param to string and outputs it in the stdout (your console).

It might be easier for you to use a debugger, though. You can open a console debugger (think gdb) with

```
require 'debugger'; debugger
```

Be sure to install [the debugger gem](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) first. Put the following in your Gemfile

```
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Edit: added a link to the debugger gem's github page.

Comment: I'm trying to implement `puts` in my views, but its not even printing out a test I'm doing: <%= puts "test" %>, I even tried <%= print "test" %>, no working?

Comment: I expected the `puts` to be within your controller (within `@lv.each do`). However `puts` in general should work in your view too. But it *does not* display any information in your view. It displays it in your console (where you typed `rails server`).

Comment: It is better to use `p` than `puts` for debugging since it will print more useful info (e. g. `nil` instead of nothing)

Comment: You should really give some effort and learn how to use the debugger. I'm not sure why ruby community don't always use it - it is way better than a puts or p command. After you print something, now that you know the result, you might want to know what is in other variable. Since debugger stops the flow, you can just look in the other variable without a new request and code edit. Time saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can just log it in your console.

```
Rails.logger.info key.inspect # or whichever's value you want to check
```

It's also helpful when checking objects

Comment: Sorry for this newbie question, but can you explain where I would put this? I have the loop in my controller. Not sure where I should apply the code you provided?

Comment: if you want to check the key in every iteration of the loop, you can place it inside the `@lv.each do |key, tags|` loop